# Entity Framework SaveChanges() NullReferenceException, DisplayNameAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm stuck and looking for any ideas.

I have one entity that fails on save changes (all other entities work).
I have stripped away my code and attributes to reproduce with nothing extra.
I have checked that I can save changes accessing SQL Server directly.
I have refreshed the EF model, by dropping the entity and re-adding it.
This stripped down code involves no DisplayNames.

EF 6.1

Here is the failing test code:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void SaveEntity_ChangeData_ExpectNoErrors()
    {
        CaseEntities caseEntities = new CaseEntities();
        // Get an existing Entity (this line works)
        var entity = caseEntities.RecordsDistributionPreferences.Find("0001");
        // Change a field
        entity.ModifiedBy = "duncan";

        // get row version before save
        byte[] rowVersionBefore = entity.RowVersion;

        // Save Changes (this next line throws null reference exeption)
        caseEntities.SaveChanges();

        // get row version after save
        byte[] rowVersionAfter = entity.RowVersion;

        // Check that row version are different
        Assert.AreNotEqual(BitConverter.ToInt64(rowVersionBefore.Reverse().ToArray(), 0), BitConverter.ToInt64(rowVersionAfter.Reverse().ToArray(), 0));
    }
```

Exeception and StackTrace:

```
NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
at System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute.GetHashCode()
at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.InternalGetHashCode(T item)
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T value)
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(Type type)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<GetAttributes>b__3(PropertyInfo pi)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildPropertyValidator(PropertyInfo clrProperty)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildValidatorsForProperties(IEnumerable`1 clrProperties, IEnumerable`1 edmProperties, IEnumerable`1 navigationProperties)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildTypeValidator[T](Type clrType, IEnumerable`1 edmProperties, IEnumerable`1 navigationProperties, Func`3 validatorFactoryFunc)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildEntityValidator(InternalEntityEntry entityEntry)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationProvider.GetEntityValidator(InternalEntityEntry entityEntry)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.GetValidationResult(IDictionary`2 items)
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary`2 items)
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at SCC.Case.Entities.Test.RecordsDistributionPreferenceTest.SaveEntity_ChangeData_ExpectNoErrors() in c:\Dev\SCC\Case\Dev\src\SCC.Case.Entities.Test\RecordsDistributionPreferenceTest.cs:line 40
```

Comment: Why are your unit tests hitting the database? That makes it an integration test.

Comment: I created this unit test solely to try to debug this issue.  This was the easiest place for me to write some quick debug code to strip away the layers of application code.  Once the issue is resolve I would delete this temporary unit test.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

The problem was with a different entity that the saving entity had a foreign key to.  This other entity was simply missing a localized resource item for the DisplayName.

I found the issue my stripping all the foreign keys for the offending DB table, then refreshing the DataModel (from DB).  Error was gone.    So I added each foreign key back, refresh, tested until I got the error.  Then I took a look at the DisplayNames for the foreign key entity and found one missing. 

Answer (score -2):

i suggest you to put Try Catch and watch inner message, there you will see what's happen and what variable gets null.

```
try{
        CaseEntities caseEntities = new CaseEntities();
        // Get an existing Entity (this line works)
        var entity = caseEntities.RecordsDistributionPreferences.Find("0001");
        // Change a field
        entity.ModifiedBy = "duncan";

        // get row version before save
        byte[] rowVersionBefore = entity.RowVersion;

        // Save Changes (this next line throws null reference exeption)
        caseEntities.SaveChanges();

        // get row version after save
        byte[] rowVersionAfter = entity.RowVersion;

        // Check that row version are different
        Assert.AreNotEqual(BitConverter.ToInt64(rowVersionBefore.Reverse().ToArray(), 0), BitConverter.ToInt64(rowVersionAfter.Reverse().ToArray(), 0));
    }
catch (NullReferenceException ex){

}
```

put a breakPoint in the Catch line, and watch inner Message